# how to print all the array (pokeapi)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pokeapi

I have this code where Im trying to print the content of the *'stats'* array from the pokeapi, but when the function is called in the browser I just get the last element of that array.

How to get it all in the HTML side?
Thanks!

main.js:

```
fetch(apiURL).then(response => {
 response.json();
  }
.then(data => {

  let array 
  for(let i=0; i<data.stats.length; i++ ) {
    array = data.stats[i].stat.name;
    console.log(array);           // <- I have all the array content here
  }
  pokemonFoundStats = array;
  console.log(pokemonFoundStats); // <- I just get the last element from the array

  pokemonStats(pokemonFoundStats);
 }) };

 // function for printing in the html
const pokemonStats = (pokemonStatsInfo) => {
  const allStats = document.getElementById("poke-screen-id");
  allStats.value = `  Stats: ${pokemonStatsInfo}`;
};
```

HTML:
Where I try to print the array content

```
<input id="poke-screen-id" type="text" placeholder="stats">
```

Answer (score 0):

please find below the code.
Or check on code sandbox here dummy data. https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-ch6bky?file=/index.js

```
fetch(apiURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let array = [];
    for(let i=0; i<data.stats.length; i++ ) {
      array.push(data.stats[i].stat.name;);
      // console.log(array);           
      pokemonStats(array);
    }
  });
// function for printing in the html
const pokemonStats = (pokemonStatsInfo) => {
  const allStats = document.getElementById("poke-screen-id");
  allStats.value = `Stats: ${pokemonStatsInfo}`;
};
```